# Formula with changing multipliers within range of numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to create a formula where different values within a range of numbers are multiplied by different multipliers. For example, the number 50:
Values 1-10 are multiplied by 100, values 11-20 are multiplied by 50, values above 21 are multiplied by 20, and then it is all summed up.

For the number 50, the result will be:

```
((10 x 100) + (10 x 50) + (40 x 20)) = 2300
```

If the number is 25, the result would be:

```
((10 x 100) + (10 x 50) + (5 x 20)) = 1600
```

If the number is 13, the result would be:

```
((10 x 100) + (3 x 50)) = 1150
```

If the number is 8, the result would be:

```
8 x 100 = 800
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably prettier ways to do this but here's one:

```
=IF(A1>=10,1000,A1*100)+IF(A1>=20,500,MAX(0,A1-10)*50)+MAX(0,A1-20)*20
```

It's really 3 different bits added together.

```
IF(A1>=10,1000,A1*100)
IF(A1>=20,500,MAX(0,A1-10)*50)
MAX(0,A1-20)*20
```

If you're not in a situation where you have to manually set the cell reference (instead of setting it once then copy/paste) and you have a newer version of Excel, you can use the `LET()` function to make it easier to change the cell reference manually:

```
=LET(val,A1,IF(val>=10,1000,val*100)+IF(val>=20,500,MAX(0,val-10)*50)+MAX(0,val-20)*20)
```

---

<sup>FYI: You have an error in your example for 50. It should be:</sup>
<sup>((10 x 100) + (10 x 50) + (**30** x 20)) = **2100**</sup>

Comment: oh, I see, so simple!... thanks heaps! it works now... genius!

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(C1<=10,C1*100,IF(AND(C1>10,C1<=20),10*100+(C1-10)*50,IF(C1>20,10*100+10*50+(C1-20)*20)))
```

[image]